# Double category construction from a functor to $\mathbf{Cat}$

Tags: category-theory

Let $\mathbf{M}$ be a single-object category and $F$ a functor from $\mathbf{M}$ to $\mathbf{Cat}$. Let $X$ be image of the single object of $\mathbf{M}$ by $F$. It seems to me that the data of $F$ allows one to construct a double category $\mathbf{D}$ as follows:

- The objects of $\mathbf{D}$ are those of $X$,
- The horizontal morphisms of $\mathbf{D}$ are those of $X$
- The vertical morphisms are the images of the morphisms of $\mathbf{M}$ by $F$, and thus compose like the morphisms of $\mathbf{M}$
- Squares arise since the images of the morphisms of $\mathbf{M}$ are functors

Is this construction valid, and is it already known ?

My motivation comes from considering a category of open subsets and inclusion, and considering an additional group action on open subsets.

Comment: How do you define exactly the vertical morphisms? My best guess is, if $a,b$ are objects of $X$, the vertical morphisms are morphisms $f$ in $M$ such that $F(f)(a) = b$. I always tend to be careful when categories test equality on their objects, because it makes the construction not invariant by equivalence of categories

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I'm thinking of.

Comment: I don't know this construction, and I think its well-definedness depends on your definition of category. If you consider all the objects of your category up to isomorphism, then this is not properly defined. Indeed consider the case where you have an object $a$ in $X$, and a functor $f$ in $M$, together with an object $b$ in $X$ which is isomorphic to $F(f)(a)$, but no morphism between $F(f)(a)$ and $b$ are images of isos of $F$. Then according to your construction, there is a vertical morphism between $a$ and $F(f)(a)$, but none between $a$ and $b$, even though $a$ and $b$ are isomorphic

Comment: That being said, many constructions on categories are used although they have this bias, and a lot of people work with categories, considering their objects distinguishable even when they might be isomorphic. I think in the later case your construction is valid. However, note that if you consider the such categories, you have to be very careful. Firstly, it contradicts the usage (everything is usually invariant under isomorphism). Secondly, it means that limits and colimits are not unique, but any two are isomorphic, and you have to always distinguish statements about equality and isomorphisms

Comment: I always considered categories to have distinguishable objects even when isomorphic. Now I see the problems you're mentionning in the alternative case. Thank you for pointing them out.

Comment: So, basically we have a monoid of endofunctors on $X$. Exactly what will be the squares?

Comment: I was thinking of commuting diagrams between objects of $X$ arising from the fact that the images of the morphisms of $M$ are functors.

Comment: Assume $\alpha:a\to b$ and $\beta:c\to d$ are arrows in $X$ and $f, g:X\to X$ with $f(a)=c$ and $g(b)=d$. When would such a square be 'commutative'?

Comment: I probably explained it in a wrong way. What I'm thinking of is that, if $\alpha \colon a \to b$ is an arrow in $X$, then for a given $f \colon X \to X$ we have a square with horizontal morphisms $a$ and $f(a)$ and vertical morphisms $f$.

Comment: That makes sense. What I see problematic is that, on an object, possibility many vertical morphisms could act as identity. If that issue can be resolved, then I guess, these will be exactly the double categories such that each pair $(h:A\to B,\ v:A\downarrow C)$ extends uniquely to a square (and possibly some further conditions)..